# Evaluating $T(n)=T(n-1)+c\log(n)$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

> $$T(n)=T(n-1)+c\log(n)$$
>   where $T(1)=d$

$$T(n)-T(n-1)=c\log(n)$$
$$T(n)-T(1)=c\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(n)$$
$$T(n)-d=c\cdot n\cdot \log(n)$$
$$T(n)=c\cdot n\cdot \log(n)+d$$

So $T(n)=O(n\log(n))$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be 
$$ T(n) =c \log(n! e^{d}). $$

Comment: we take $c\cdot n$ to be $c$ as it is a constant?

Comment: assuming $c$ is a constant (meaning $c$ does not depend on $n$)

Answer (score 1):

The equation
$$
T(n)=T(n-1)+c\cdot\ln(n)
$$
yields
$$
T(n-1)=T(n-2)+c\cdot\ln(n-1)\\
T(n-2)=T(n-3)+c\cdot\ln(n-2)\\
\vdots
$$
We can conclude
$$
T(n)=T(n-1)+c\cdot\ln(n)=T(n-2)+c\cdot\ln(n-1)+c\cdot\ln(n)=\ldots\\
=T(1)+c\sum_{k=2}^n\ln(k)
=d+c\sum_{k=2}^n\ln(k).
$$

If we simplify
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n\ln(k)=\ln(n!),
$$
then we get
$$
T(n)=d+c\cdot\ln(n!).
$$

Comment: if it was $T(n)=T(n-2)+log(n)$ we would get $T(n)=d+log(n)+log(n-2)+...log(2)$ how could we sum the log elements ?

Comment: Are you consider an other equation with $T(n)=T(n-2)+\log(n)$? That is a different problem. To sum the log elements, you can use $\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$ which is well known. More general we have $\sum_{i=1}^n\log(a_i)=\log\left(\prod_{i=1}^na_i\right)$.

Comment: If you consider the equation $T(n)=T(n-2)+\log(n)$ then the main idea is the same, but you have to modify is. First, you need to define $T(1)$ and $T(2)$ and further, you have to consider $n$ even and odd for your formula.